# Android: How to get an additional onClickListener to communicate with a Switch statement?

Tags: android, onclick, switch-statement, onclicklistener

I am developing an app that has a question with a multiple choice component.

So far, I've used a Switch statement to display three different questions as TextViews and its choices as Buttons.

Like this:

```
public void onClick (View v)
{
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.firstOption:
            mainQuestion.setText("Mexico’s capital is");
            answerOne.setText("Monterrey");
            answerTwo.setText("Cancun");
            answerThree.setText("Mexico City");
            answerFour.setText("Acapulco");
            break;
        case R.id.secondOption:
            mainQuestion.setText("Canada’s capital is");
            answerOne.setText("Vancouver");
            answerTwo.setText("Edmonton");
            answerThree.setText("Toronto");
            answerFour.setText("Ottawa");
            break;
        case R.id.thirdOption:
            mainQuestion.setText("Spain’s current currency is the");
            answerOne.setText("Yen");
            answerTwo.setText("Euro");
            answerThree.setText("Pound");
            answerFour.setText("Dollar");
            break;
    }

}
```

What I can't figure out is how to handle when the user presses a `Button` to make a choice.

How can I get it to communicate with each case?

I've tried creating an additional `onClickListener`, but I can't get it to work, so I am back to square one.

Could you guys help me out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, a button can only listen for a click event. Your onclick method in the OnClickListener callback is same as the global onClick(View v) that you used. If you want to add more action, you might consider OnLongClickListener. What you have up there looks fine to me, you have defined what you want to happen when user makes a choice.

Furthermore, you might want to give the container of the button and the textviews an id and call the onclick(View v) method on the container instead so that the button can do different thing, which of course will do it base on what user select.

You might use a boolean to check if the container has been clicked, so when the boolean is true, the button can perform action otherwise is disabled, if you know what I mean. Hope this help.